# Vscode installation optional task

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, path

When passing through vscode selection process, there is an one option that seems confusing.

> Add to PATH (requires shell restart)

What does shell refers to? The powershell? Explorer.exe? Or another else? How to restart shell after Vscode installation?

Answer (score 0):

By adding `VSCode` to PATH, you will be able to run some commands related to this IDE anywhere in your operating system.

**For Example:** This command inside command-line will open `VSCode` in the current directory:

```sh
code .
```

**Note:** For your second question, you don't need to restart shell. It will be done automatically.